# Java - StackOverflowError - access HashMaps

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I am getting a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` when attempting to call a method within another class.

I think the problem is due to each class being instantiated within each other but I'm not sure as to why it causes this error or how to fix it.

Method call from Main():

```
    nexaConnect.returnAllChronologicalByRoom("bathroomSensorMappings");
```

Logic():

```
public class Logic {
  private SensorMaps mapAccess = new SensorMaps();

  void returnAllChronologicalByRoom(String room) {
    System.out.print(mapAccess.returnMap(room).get(0));
  }
}
```

SensorMaps:

```
public class SensorMaps {
  private Logic sensorConnect = new Logic();

  HashMap<Integer, String> returnMap(String mapChoice) {
    return MapRegistry.find(mapChoice);
  }
}
```

There is a third MapRegistry class but I don't think this is causing issues but I'll include it for completeness:

MapRegistry:

```
class MapRegistry {
  static Map<String,HashMap<Integer,String>> allMaps = new HashMap<>();

  static void register(String name, HashMap<Integer,String> myMap) {
    allMaps.put(name, myMap);
  }

  static HashMap<Integer,String> find(String name) {
    return allMaps.get(name);
  }
}
```

The two key lines in the error output:

```
at com.company.SensorMaps.<init>(SensorMaps.java:11)
at com.company.Logic.<init>(Logic.java:19)
```

Refer to lines:

```
private Logic sensorConnect = new Logic();
private SensorMaps mapAccess = new SensorMaps();
```

The full error output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.company.SensorMaps.<init>(SensorMaps.java:11)
    at com.company.Logic.<init>(Logic.java:19)
    at com.company.SensorMaps.<init>(SensorMaps.java:11)
    at com.company.Logic.<init>(Logic.java:19)
    ...
    at com.company.SensorMaps.<init>(SensorMaps.java:11)
    at com.company.Logic.<init>(Logic.java:19)
```

Comment: read the stack trace: line 19 of Logic calls Line 11 of SensorMaps which calls again line 19 of Logic.  An infinite recursion, therefore a StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Logic` class creates an instance of `SensorMaps` whenever it is instantiated.

```
private SensorMaps mapAccess = new SensorMaps();
```

Your `SensorMaps` class creates an instance of `Logic` whenever it is instantiated.

```
private Logic sensorConnect = new Logic();
```

Hence, whenever you create an instance of one of these two classes, you get into an infinite loop that ends in `StackOverflowError`.

You should re-consider your logic, and eliminate at least one of these instance variables (or change on of them to a static variable if it makes sense).

I don't see where you are using `sensorConnect`, so I don't know if it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks, `private Logic sensorConnect = new Logic();` was supposed to have been removed, there was an old method that should have been migrated out that was still there which was using the Logic class.